# How do you convert any file(text, image, etc) into binary format using Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do you convert any file(text, image, etc) into binary format using Node? I cant seem to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile('image.jpg', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Encode to base64
  var encodedImage = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64');

  // Decode from base64
  var decodedImage = new Buffer(encodedImage, 
    'base64').toString('binary');
});
```

Credits: Arkar Aung

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toString` method to convert file content string data to `base64`.

example:

```
var fs   = require('fs'),  
data = fs.readFileSync('./myfile.txt');
console.log(data.toString('base64'));
```

Read More: https://icodealot.com/convert-data-to-base64-in-nodejs/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but  I want to convert into binary format. 0s and 1s. Not Base64